# What can come out from mystery eggs?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I have just reached Level 231+ and I'm curious, what are all the possible things that can come out from mystery eggs?

I've personally seen chocolates, candy bombs, striped candies, blocks, fish, and doughnuts.

Can I only get things that I have seen before in previous levels? Or is it possible to get things that will only be formally introduced in future levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every element and blocker can come out from Mystery Candies. You can check out this whole article here if you like:

http://candy-crush-saga.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Candy

Answer (score 2):

I have seen everything possible come out of the mystery eggs. FYI, no further candy type is introduced, the only things that are added from level 231 to the end are things which aren't specific to a single square. I've seen switching candies come out, frozen candies, and just about everything else. In addition, there is the checked candy, which only appears if you are on a candy order level. But as there doesn't appear to be any new types that come out after that level, it doesn't seem to matter.